# ModPerl::Registry - Cannot run CGI perl script

Tags: perl, mod-perl2

I'm under Apache 2.4.7 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm trying to run the following basic perl script (/home/fred/workspace/portfolio/cgi/fred.pl) under [`ModPerl::Registry`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/mod_perl/docs/api/ModPerl/Registry.pod) but it won't execute (the browser treats it as a file to download, not a perl script)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hi Fred !";
```

This is my virtual host configuration :

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/fred/workspace/portfolio/html

AddHandler perl-script .cgi .pl
PerlModule ModPerl::Registry
Alias / /home/fred/workspace/portfolio/cgi/
<Location />
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
        Require all granted
        Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

I previously run

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

which actually enabled cgid (my apache is threaded), fine.

when I type 127.0.0.1/fred.pl, no execution (fred.pl has rights 777)

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: yes, nothing abnormal in error.log. Have this is in access.log : 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2014:14:58:06 +0200] "GET /fred.pl HTTP/1.1" 200 249 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

Comment: does it help if I say that curl http://localhost/fred.pl works ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd check is that you've got the right apache config file. (Simple way to check: put in a syntax error and see if it complains when you restart the server.)

If it's the right file, then you have an issue with your config directives. It's hard to debug those without seeing the whole file. You could try starting with a very simple config section, like the one [here](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html#toc_Registry_Scripts).

I would probably turn off cgid until you get this working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fist, `PerlHandler` handler is mod_perl1 directive. mod_perl2 has `PerlResponseHandler` handler alternative.

So following is right:

```
PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
```

And did you load mod_perl.so? When you use Ubuntu, then type:

```
sudo a2enmod perl
```

or write suitable `LoadModule` line and restart server.

Maybe, there is other problem. However I do not have enough information.

Finally I advice that mod_perl2 does not official support Apache **2.4** on now (Dec 2014).

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf file, you need to add the following line

```
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
```

This enables execution of CGI scripts in apache httpd server.

You also need to add the following line perl CGI execution permission.

```
PerlSwitches -w
```